# Give me hints for evaluating this limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right\}}^{-n}$$
Please give me some hints. If you provide a complete answer instead, please include a spoiler tag.

Comment: **Hint.** $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$

Comment: Then the part inside the curls goes to $(e-1)$. It powered to n goes to $\infty$. So, the limit is 0. Am I right? @Christian Ivicevic

Comment: If I am not overlooking anything this is true indeed. I guess you just need to explain your reasoning more detailed. Moreover you have to check whether you are allowed to apply my hint - if it is for a homework, then the question is whether you have already proven the hint in a lecture etc.

Comment: Yes. I think I'm allowed to do so. @Christian Ivicevic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x=\exp(x)$$

From here on you can easily conclude the result as you mentioned in the comments of your post.

Comment: There's one problem though. Rather, a confusion. I know that $\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)^n}=(\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)})^n$. But, can the same be said when $n$ is replaced with $x$ itself?

Comment: @SayantanSantra No $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)} \ne (\lim_{x \to a} f(x))^{g(x)}$  Unless $g$ is constant function

Comment: Then? How would I solve it? @Ekaveera Kumar Sharma

Comment: By applying Log on both sides

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^{-n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-1+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(-1+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(-n\ln\left(-1+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}-n\ln\left(-1+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(-\lim_{n\to\infty}n\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(-1+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$